# Spring Security Reactive WebFilterChainProxy only calling a single filter chain

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

I need to add security into a Webflux based app and have requirements that mean I need to add multiple filter chains. However, the current implementation of `WebFilterChainProxy` uses `Flux.filterWhen(...)` which, if I'm reading the docs correctly, will only ever return the first match in the chain.

Given the above I have three questions:-

1. My react knowledge is very limited, can someone confirm if my understanding of what `filterWhen` does is correct?
2. If so, can anyone suggest a way to get multiple filter chains to work in the new Spring Security 5 reactive model?
3. If I have misunderstood how the filterWhen method works, could any one make any suggestions why only one of my filter chains is processed?

The way I am adding filters to the chain is in multiple configuration methods annotated with `@Order`, similar to the code block below.

```
@Configration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig
    ...
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    SecurityWebFilterChain chain1(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.httpBasic().disable()......
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    SecurityWebFilterChain chain2(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.httpBasic().disable()......
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(3)
    SecurityWebFilterChain chain3(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.httpBasic().disable()......
    }
    ...
}
```

When I debug the application I can see that all three filters have been added to the `WebFilterChainProxy` but I only ever get one matched filter back. I need to find a way of returning all filters that match.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5395 is the bug for this above issue on Spring Security

Answer (score 3):

I was able to finally resolve this by using [ServerWebExchangeMatchers](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/server/util/matcher/ServerWebExchangeMatchers.java). My use case involved enabling Basic Authentication when accessing Spring Actuator endpoints and no authentication on other paths. I was able to accomplish this by the following code:

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity httpSecurity) 
{
    httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            .logout().disable()
            .formLogin().disable();


 httpSecurity.securityMatcher(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("/actuator/**"))
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/actuator/**")
            .hasRole(ACTUATOR_ADMIN_ROLE);

    return httpSecurity.build();
}
```

Comment: In the end I actually ended up doing something very similar but didn't post as an answer because it is actually subtly different. Using the method you describe (and 
also the method that I Implemented) ONLY a single filter chain will be applied when I actually wanted to apply multiple ones. I will add my own answer now but thank you for responding!

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering my own question(s) here in the hope it might help the underdstanding of others.

> 1. My react knowledge is very limited, can someone confirm if my understanding of what filterWhen does is correct?

Yes, my understanding here is correct, `Flux.filterWhen(...)` will return only the first item matched.

> 2. If so, can anyone suggest a way to get multiple filter chains to work in the new Spring Security 5 reactive model?

Multiple filter chains 'work' out-of-box in the Reactive parts of Spring Security 5, they just work in a mutually exclusive way, e.g. only a single filter will be applied given the use of `Flux.filterWhen(...)`.

> 3. If I have misunderstood how the filterWhen method works, could any one make any suggestions why only one of my filter chains is processed?

See the answer to 2. above.

From a wider perspective, my original requirement was to have multiple chains, where more than one chain would be applied but, given the constraints already outlined, this simply wasn't possible. I had to modify what we were doing so that it worked with the framework rather than against it.

We still required multiple filter chains as security requirements were different for different flows and we ended up using the same [ServerWebExchangeMatchers](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/server/util/matcher/ServerWebExchangeMatchers.java) in a similar manner as described in @KRam answer.

Comment: So how would you support multiple authentication methods on one endpoint? For example, I want to be able to access the /api endpoint by either presenting a JWT or using a userid and password.

Comment: @mbluke, My situation was different to what you're looking for and I'm not in this area any longer but I'd think you could extend `AuthenticationWebFilter` and pass in a custom authenticator via the `setAuthenticationConverter` method. Inside your custom authenticator you can determine what method you wish to use based on request header information and delgate to a specific implementation.